# Notice undefined index all_resource vendor/magento/module-integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration.php

Tags: magento2

there are 3rd party developers who are trying to set up API account and they got this error. They need to feed product data from their NutriLoader software so they need to set up API account.

They went to below path to set up API account.
System > Extension (Integrations)

System config details are as below:
PHP 5.6.20 and OS Linux
[image]